# Python - ElementTree- cannot use absolute path on element

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I'm getting this error in ElementTree when I try to run the code below:

```
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element
```

My XML document looks like this:

```
<Scripts>
  <Script>
    <StepList>
      <Step>
        <StepText>
        </StepText>
        <StepText>
        </StepText>
      </Step>
    </StepList>
  </Script>
</Scripts>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def search():
    root = ET.parse(INPUT_FILE_PATH)
    for target in root.findall("//Script"):
        print target.attrib['name']
        print target.findall("//StepText")
```

I'm on Python 2.6 on Mac.  Am I using Xpath syntax wrong?

Basically I want to show every Script elements name attribute if it contains a StepText element with certain text.

Comment: ElementTree seems a naff implementation. It should allow absolute paths like //SOURCE/text()

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Turns out I needed to say `target.findall(".//StepText")`.  I guess anything without the '.' is considered an absolute path?

Updated working code:

```
def search():
    root = ET.parse(INPUT_FILE_PATH)
    for target in root.findall("//Script"):
        stepTexts = target.findall(".//StepText")
        for stepText in stepTexts:
            if FIND.lower() in stepText.text.lower():
                print target.attrib['name'],' -- ',stepText.text
```

Comment: Any XPath expression starting with `/` or `//` operator is an absolute expression. Besides this, that restriction (absolute expressions not allowed with other context node than root) is specific to your XPath engine implementation.

Comment: @user357812 is there a way to query which engine a particular XPath implementation is using?